# Chart - Disable Series by Checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, charts

I am trying to enable and disable line points on a chart with checkboxes. 
However when I am clicking the checkboxes the x axis which are set to DateTime are changing! It is quite annoying. Here is an example of the pictures before and afterwards below.

[image]

This is the image after selecting the check box. 
I would like to try and stop this from happening and add check boxes for each series so I can enable and disable the lines. Then the user can just view one at a time.

The code is below:

[image]

```
private void radCheckBox1_ToggleStateChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.StateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (radCheckBox1.Checked == false)
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < HRM.Active.DataRows.Count; x++)
            {
                chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(x, 
                       HRM.Active.DataRows.ElementAt(x).Speed);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a little confusing, to be honest. From your other post I would have thought that the series data are databound to a DataTable. Now you seem to add them in a loop from, what is `HRM`? Looking at the chart and the lables I guess the xValues are not consistently interpreted. Can you try: `Points.AddXY(x.ToOADate(), ...);` instead?

Comment: It is confusing me as well, hmmm no that does not work. Its a difficult one.

Comment: `DateTimes` in `Chart` are not very intuitve, as the values will internally always be mapped to `double`. My answer should work very simply, though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to make Series disappear and come back again is like so:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Series sz = chart1.Series["Zeroes"];
    sz.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
}
```

One more note on the code and the images you posted:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(x, HRM.Active.DataRows.ElementAt(x).Speed);
```

is not guaranteed to add the X-Values as the dates they may be. Instead you might need to use this conversion:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(x.ToOADate(),
                                      HRM.Active.DataRows.ElementAt(x).Speed);
```

but not knowing anything about your actuall data, I can't be sure about this. But do keep in mind: `DateTimes` in `Chart` are not very intuitve, as the values will internally always be mapped to `double`.

But using the `Enabled` property you don't need all the messy clearing and re-adding any `DataPoints` anyway!

Comment: Your work at the top worked, however when you disable the First Series I have it changes to the X Axis. Interesting, but that way does enable and disable it.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to keep the 1st series, as this seems to be the one that rules the x-axis in your chart! Only its XValueMember is set, right?

Comment: Fixed, thank you! Only the first series was set to Date/Time. So I set each of the others to Date/Time. Then when you enable and disable the series how you said in this post it worked. :) Setting the XValueMember as Date/Time on all however only allows me to have a certain number of points on the graph initially but the zoom function helps see more.